# Variable pronunciation of patach chataf in Lithuanian Hebrew

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, ashkenazi, vowels-nekudot

In theory, a "patach chataf" - a patach with a shva next to it, like this:

חֲ

is pronounced in Lithuanian Hebrew like a patach followed by a yud.

This results in the common pronunciations (which I have even heard amongst those who are not Litvish) "Mairiv", "gaiva", and "maiseh".

Is there a rule for how this pronunciation is applied?  It seems irregular as I have never heard "rachaimim", "ahaiva", or "chaidasha".  How about "Ya'aikov"?

Comment: i only hear it from when their is a chataf patach on an ayin or alef, so yakov would be yaikov, and maamar would be maimar

Comment: Maybe that's why it became Yankov and Yankel

Comment: @Efraim that may explain alot!

Comment: @Efraim that sounds right to me, now I wonder if there's any source that spells it out.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin IMHO it is exactly the reason for Yankel and Yankov, just an exaggeration of "ay"

Comment: Where did you get this theory from? There aren't sources that prescribe pronunciation.

Comment: @DoubleAA there aren't any sources that discuss pronunciation? Really?

Comment: If you want to know how Chasidei X today pronounce a Kubbutz, just ask them. That's basically the only way. It's _exceedingly_ rare to find detailed description of sounds in Jewish literature.

Comment: @DoubleAA for the record, I'm not interested in perfectly replicating any particular havara, I'm just interested in havaros in general, how they formed, and what their rules, whether deliberate or natural, are. Also, to answer your comment prior to your edit, Breslov doesn't have any particular pronunciation. :)

Comment: Fwiw: yaa3qob became Yankle becuse Ashkenazim can't pronounce the 3ayeen. Just like shama3 became shamang.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, actually, ע being pronounced as "ng" was the accepted pronunciation in the Spanish-Portuguese diaspora in Amsterdam and London. It was also used in some regions of Germany. I suspect that it has something to do with how עזה became Gaza and עמורה became Gomorrah (ע became guttural Greek *Γ* [gamma] which eventually became became *ngayin*)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt accepted because they to couldnt pronounce the ayeen. ng is as close as you get when trying hard and not succeeding

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, actually, I think that 3ayin is easier to pronounce than ngayin, at least when one is doing so according to grammatical usage (e.g. Ya3akov vs. Yangakov vs. Yangkov)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt the ng is the 3ayeen. they didnt pronounce it as an arabic 3'ayeen'/ghayeen. they just couldnt pronounce the ayeen properly. so making ng in the back of the throat is as close as they got

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, I know. I'm saying that the guttural is significantly easier than inserting a whole other phoneme.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt its not a whole other phoneme. they dont actualyl say yangkov. the letter n is not said in the front of the mounth but mixed with the g at the back of the mouth. they just cant make it in the back of the throat. so it sounds like ya3aqov but not in the back of the throat. it might be easier for you but its not easier for most ashkanazim